# Running electron on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, electron

I'm trying to make a project I coded on Mac OS run in Windows and it uses Electron. I tried running it like this:

```
node node_modules\.bin\electron
```

and it doesn't work:

```
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\ProjectX\node_modules\.bin\electron:3:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Webpack works in that fashion:

```
>node .\node_modules\.bin\webpack --version
Hash: a9840b6c5503dc0a037c
Version: webpack 1.13.3
```

Any ideas what's the problem with Electron and/or how to fix it? The script contains this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var electron = require('./')

var proc = require('child_process')

var child = proc.spawn(electron, process.argv.slice(2), {stdio: 'inherit'})
child.on('close', function (code) {
  process.exit(code)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run Electron on Windows like so:

```
> node_modules\.bin\electron.cmd
```

However, since you want to develop on both macOS and Windows you should just add an NPM script to your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "app": "electron ."
}
```

Then you can use the same command to run it on any OS:

```
> npm run app
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that when I copied my code from a Mac to a Win 10 machine, because I had unfinished changes I didn't want to commit, I also copied the node_modules, so I had the Mac/Linux/Unix ones that includes files that have a plain name in .bin and use the shebang to call for the right interpreter.

Once I deleted the node_modules and I re-installed, in the .bin, I got those plain name files but also .cmd files. The plain electron looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/../electron/cli.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
  node  "$basedir/../electron/cli.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $ret
```

while electron.cmd looks like this:

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\..\electron\cli.js" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node  "%~dp0\..\electron\cli.js" %*
)
```